# Given two NFAs, is there a way to figure out if there exists a language that works for both of them?

Tags: automata

Given two non-deterministic finite automaton, is there a way to determine if there exists a single language that satisfies them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an algorithm to convert them to deterministic finite-state automata. Then you can use any of the algorithms mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194112/deciding-equivalence-of-regular-languages/194289#comment447350_194289) and the answers to it.